# Spring Boot - Create bean when property set otherwise create default bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Basically I want to create a concrete bean if a property is set and some sort of *NoopBean* with the same interface but which does nothing.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can describe both object as beans which creation depends on your custom condition. The configuration may look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfiguration {

  @Bean(name="concreteBean")
  @Conditional(YourCondition.class)
  public YourInterface concreteBean(){
      return new ConcreteBean();
  }

  @Bean(name="noopBean")
  @Conditional(YourCondition.class)
  public YourInterface noopBean(){
    return new NoopBean();
  }

}
```

The [@Conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783022/spring-boot-create-bean-when-property-set-otherwise-create-default-bean) annotation can be alternatively used with classes annotated with `@Component` which rely on component scan process.

You also need a class, which will describe the condition, e.g.:

```
public class YourCondition implements Condition {

    @Override 
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return "concret".equals(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("your.property"));
    }

}
```

Having a class which describes the condition is highly flexible, but if you simply want to check a property, you can use a more specialized version of the `@Condition` which is [@ConditionalOnProperty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) and get rid of the condition class. In that case, you describe the condition directly in the annotation on your beans.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="your.property", havingValue="concret")
```

The disadvantage in that case is that you need to repeat the same condition in each bean. A simple `@Conditional` with a separate class is recommended as it can get a proper meaningful name.

Answer (score 2):

One option is:

```
@Bean
public MyInterface myBean() {
    if (somePropertySet) {
       return new RealBean();
    } else {
       return new NoOpBean();
    }
}
```

Another option is to use spring profiles.

```
@Bean
@Profile("noop-profile")
public MyInterface myBean() {
   return new NoOpBean();
}

@Bean
@Profile("real-profile")
public MyInterface myBean() {
   return new RealBean();
}
```

The 2nd options may make sense if you are already using spring profiles (e.g. "production", "staging" etc.)